# Convert mysql query into magento model format

Tags: php, mysql, magento, join, zend-framework

I have the following query that I am trying to convert in Magento Model format, but the result is not the same after conversion and getting same errors.

**Query is:**

```
SELECT 
  ce_varchar.value AS CODE,

  sfoi.order_id,

  sfo.increment_id,

  COUNT(sfoi.`order_id`) AS totalOrders,

  ea.attribute_id,

  ea.attribute_code,

  pv.value,

  sfo.created_at 

FROM
  mage_catalog_product_entity AS ce

  INNER JOIN mage_eav_attribute AS ea

    ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id

  INNER JOIN mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar

    ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id 

    AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id 

    AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar' 

  INNER JOIN mage_sales_flat_order_item AS sfoi 

    ON sfoi.product_id = ce.entity_id 

  INNER JOIN mage_sales_flat_order AS sfo 

    ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id 

  INNER JOIN mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar pv 

    ON pv.entity_id = ce.entity_id 

WHERE ea.attribute_id = 1062 

  AND pv.attribute_id = 96 

  AND LOWER(sfo.lead_status) IN ('converted', 'unconverted') 

  AND ce_varchar.value IS NOT NULL
```

**Here is my Failed attempt of Magento's Model Formatted query**

```
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
       ->join(array('ea'=>'eav/attribute'),
            'ea.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id',array(''))
        ->join(array('ce_varchar'=>'catalog/product_entity_varchar'),
            'main_table.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id')

        ->join(array('sfoi'=>'sales/flat_order_item'),
            'sfoi.product_id = ce.entity_id',array(''))
        ->join(array('sfo'=>'sales/flat_order'),
            'sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id ',array(''))
        ->join(array('pv'=>'catalog/product_entity_varchar'),
            'pv.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',array(''))
            ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('cut_sample_location')
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('tatalOrders','COUNT(sfoi.`order_id`)','sfoi.order_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('ea.attribute_id',1062)
         ->addFieldToFilter('pv.attribute_id',96)
           ->addFieldToFilter('sfo.lead_status', array('in' => array('converted',
                        'unconverted')))
        ->addFieldToFilter('ce_varchar.value' != null) 

        ->group('main_table.entity_id , ce_varchar.value')
        ->order('DESC')
        ->limit(30);
```

Comment: Can you describe witch kind of information are you trying to retrive? It seems a little bit messy in this way. Just try to add a simple list with a small description if needed.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve total number of orders on the bases of custom product attribute i.e is" cut_sample_location" and filtering orders by field called lead status